# SQL: parse a column delimited (shorten the script)

Tags: sql, plsql

I created a query and it's properly working.. but I'm not yet satisfied because my code is too long, is there  way that I can simplify or shorten my select statement ?

```
select   
/*GenInfo*/
 id ,name name,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'EntityID=[^;]*'), 'EntityID=', '') as EntityID,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'deployed=[^;]*'), 'deployed=', '') as deployed,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'type=[^;]*'), 'type=', '') as type,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'level=[^;]*'), 'level=', '') as "LEVEL",
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'description=[^;]*'), 'description=', '') as description,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'indicator=[^;]*'), 'indicator=', '') as indicator,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'Agreement=[^;]*'), 'Agreement=', '') as Agreement,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'Activation date to charge=[^;]*'), 'Activation date to charge=', '') as Activationdatetocharge,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'id=[^;]*'), 'id=', '') as id,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'name=[^;]*'), 'name=', '') as name,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'currencyCode=[^;]*'), 'currencyCode=', '') as currencyCode,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'saleExpirationDate=[^;]*'), 'saleExpirationDate=', '') as saleExpirationDate,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'Product type=[^;]*'), 'Product type=', '') as Producttype,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'saleEffectiveDate=[^;]*'), 'saleEffectiveDate=', '') as saleEffectiveDate,
replace(regexp_substr(properties, 'Deactivation date to charge=[^;]*'), 'Deactivation date to charge=', '') as Deactivationdatetocharge
.
.
.
.
.
.

from OFFER
where name = 'PLAN 599'
```

;

Comment: It looks good as you have to replace different values to generate different columns.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek, since this is a hard coded script, possible that I missed some field  and I want to catch all field? Is there a way that I can catch all not declaring the fields one by one ?

Comment: Can you update sample data and expected to understand your situation better.

Comment: @Vivek , see sample delimited, I added two values 
the  SubType;Rate;

    EntityID;deployed;type;level;description;indicator;Agreement;Activation date to charge;id;name;currencyCode;saleExpirationDate;Product type;saleEffectiveDate;Deactivation date to charge;SubType;Rate;

my Question is how can I catch the values that I added ? is there kind of  loop the we can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to double-split and generate a query:

1. Split Row into "ColName=Value"-fields
2. Split fields into two seperate vars
3. Create a from-dual-query

   DECLARE
       inputstring   VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'EntityID=1;deployed=2018-01-01;type=app';

   ```
   myquery       VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'SELECT'; -- result-var
   tmpValue      VARCHAR2 (2000);
   tmpName       VARCHAR2 (2000);
   ```

   BEGIN
       FOR i IN
       (
               SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputstring, -- Split input and loop through 
                                           '[^;]+',
                                           1,
                                           LEVEL))
                          l
                 FROM DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (inputstring, ';') + 1
       )
       LOOP
           tmpName := REGEXP_SUBSTR (i.l, '[^=]+', 1, 1); -- Split column into value and name
           tmpValue := REGEXP_SUBSTR (i.l, '[^=]+', 1, 2);
           myquery := myquery || ' ''' || tmpValue || ''' as ' || tmpName || ','; -- build some query
       END LOOP;

   ```
   myQuery := SUBSTR (myQuery, 0, LENGTH (myQuery) - 1) || ' FROM DUAL'; -- complete query

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (myQuery); --output result

   -- Result: SELECT '1' as EntityID, '2018-01-01' as deployed, 'app' as type FROM DUAL
   ```

   END;

Anyway you'll get a problem with this query if you want to read out the values by code.
Perhaps you could tell us, what you want to do with the data.

I hope, you only want to convert some data from a file. If so you can add another split-loop to split rows.

#### Example-Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MakeSQL (inputstring VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    myquery    VARCHAR2 (2000);                                  -- result-var
    tmpValue   VARCHAR2 (2000);
    tmpName    VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputstring, -- Split input and loop through
                                              '[^' || CHR (10) || ']+',
                                              1,
                                              LEVEL))
                             tmpRow
                    FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (inputstring, CHR (10)) + 1)
    LOOP
        myquery := myquery || 'SELECT';

        FOR i IN (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (x.tmpRow, -- Split input and loop through
                                                  '[^;]+',
                                                  1,
                                                  LEVEL))
                                 l
                        FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (x.tmpRow, ';') + 1)
        LOOP
            tmpName :=
                REGEXP_SUBSTR (i.l,
                               '[^=]+',
                               1,
                               1);         -- Split column into value and name
            tmpValue :=
                REGEXP_SUBSTR (i.l,
                               '[^=]+',
                               1,
                               2);
            myquery :=
                myquery || ' ''' || tmpValue || ''' as ' || tmpName || ','; -- build some query
        END LOOP;

        myQuery :=
               SUBSTR (myQuery, 0, LENGTH (myQuery) - 1)
            || ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL'
            || CHR (10);                                -- complete row-select
    END LOOP;

    myQuery := SUBSTR (myQuery, 0, LENGTH (myQuery) - 11);   -- complete query

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (myQuery);                            --output result
    RETURN myQuery;
END MakeSQL;
```

#### Example call

```
SELECT MakeSQL('EntityID=1;deployed=2018-01-01;type=app
EntityID=2;deployed=2018-02-02;type=app') FROM DUAL;
```

#### Example-Result

```
SELECT '1' as EntityID, '2018-01-01' as deployed, 'app' as type FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2' as EntityID, '2018-02-02' as deployed, 'app' as type FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Hi @kara , I want to split the data to fields

Comment: @Gabriel I know - My example does this for you and outputs the query. The question is: What do you want to do with this query?

Comment: Hi @kara , sorry , Im not familiar with codes of pl/sql , how can I display the output ?

Comment: You tool-which connects to the db has a "DBMS-Output" somewhere. I'll form a function for you. One sec.

Comment: I need to split those datas to make a report

Comment: Run the examplefunction to create a plsql-function. And do the example-call.

Comment: Amazing !! it's working !,    I will try to learn pl/sql .. thanks @kara